# C# Exception when deserialize json of Dictionary<long, SomeType>

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a bond autogenerated type A.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("bondc.exe", null)]
public partial class A : IBondSerializable, IGenericSerializer
{
       private Double m_Max;

       private BondBlob m_Data;
}
```

also to make it serializable with proper converter I had to add a partial class code in another file:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AJsonConverter))]
public partial class A
{
}
```

I want to serialize/deserialize Dictionary<long, A>

```
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.None });
serializer.Converters.Add(new AJsonConverter());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
serializer.Serialize(writer, aVariable);
writer.Flush();

var str = sb.ToString();
var aDeserialized= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, A>>(str);
```

I also created a converter to use for type A:

```
public class AJsonConverter : JsonConverter<A>
{
    public override A ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        AexistingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object obj = reader.Value;
        var res = new A();
        res.DeserializeFromBase64((string)obj);
        return res;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, A value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = value.SerializeToBase64();
        writer.WriteValue(str);
    }
}


public static void DeserializeFromBase64(this A self, string source)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (CompactBinaryProtocolReader reader = new CompactBinaryProtocolReader(stream, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            self.Read(reader);
        }
    }            
}

public static string SerializeToBase64(this A self)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CompactBinaryProtocolWriter writer = new CompactBinaryProtocolWriter(stream, leaveOpen: false))
        {
            self.Write(writer);
        }

        var res = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());

        return res;
    }
}
```

If I use this code to soly ser/deser variable of class A, it works fine. It also serialize it when I use it for Dictionary<long, A>.

But on deserialization I get an exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException   HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path '', line 1,
> position 712.   Source=Newtonsoft.Json   StackTrace:    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ThrowUnexpectedEndException(JsonReader
> reader, JsonContract contract, Object currentObject, String message)
> at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IDictionary
> dictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract,
> JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
> reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> Object existingValue)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
> reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> Object existingValue)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
> reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
> Type objectType)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
> JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
> JsonSerializerSettings settings)

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the serialized json:

```
{"1463443200000":"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"}
```

Position 712 is a position of the last bracket

While debugging I can see that it deserializes type A fine, it throws after the code leaves ReadJson function

Comment: Could you please share with us the serialized json as sample?

Comment: @PeterCsala added at the end

Comment: Can you please share with us how does class A look like?

Comment: @PeterCsala Added, but ser/deser of the class itself works fine. Thank you

Comment: Post the *actual* code and *actual JSON string. The error complains that the string ended abruptly. Why are you using BASE64 anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos posted

Comment: Is "aVariable" a Dictionary<long, A> or just an A. The json looks to me like just being an A not a Dictionary.

Comment: @Ralf aVariable is a Dictionary<long, A>. Json is {"someLong": "base64String"}

Comment: Also added Serialize/DeserializeFromBase64 functions

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this

```
var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<long, string>>(json);
```

evertything is working properly. If you want to do something with this long string, now you can do it